# Delete characters on python dataframe, the number of characters removed per line varies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
                          columnA  columnB
0  a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7|a8|a9|a10  0
1                   b1|b2||||||||  8
2                 c1|c2|c3|||||||  7
3                   d1|d2||||||||  8
4                   e1|e2||||||||  8
5         f1|f2|f3|f4|f5|f6|f7|||  3
6               g1|g2|g3|g4||||||  6
```

i want
the first line to remove 0 characters to the right,
the second line to remove 8 characters to the right,
The resulting data will have the following form

```
                          columnA  columnB
0  a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7|a8|a9|a10  0
1                   b1|b2          8
2                 c1|c2|c3         7
3                   d1|d2          8
4                   e1|e2          8
5         f1|f2|f3|f4|f5|f6|f7     3
6               g1|g2|g3|g4        6
```

Thank you very much everyone. I am a newbie and my English is not very good. Hope everyone can help me

Comment: please include your attempt at solving the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pandas' string methods on column `'columnA'`

#### [`rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```
df.columnA.str.rstrip('|')

0    a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7|a8|a9|a10
1                             b1|b2
2                          c1|c2|c3
3                             d1|d2
4                             e1|e2
5              f1|f2|f3|f4|f5|f6|f7
6                       g1|g2|g3|g4
Name: columnA, dtype: object
```

---

#### Not altering `df`

```
df.assign(columnA=df.columnA.str.rstrip('|'))

                          columnA  columnB
0  a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7|a8|a9|a10        0
1                           b1|b2        8
2                        c1|c2|c3        7
3                           d1|d2        8
4                           e1|e2        8
5            f1|f2|f3|f4|f5|f6|f7        3
6                     g1|g2|g3|g4        6
```

---

#### overwriting `df`

```
df['columnA'] = df.columnA.str.rstrip('|')
df

                          columnA  columnB
0  a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|a6|a7|a8|a9|a10        0
1                           b1|b2        8
2                        c1|c2|c3        7
3                           d1|d2        8
4                           e1|e2        8
5            f1|f2|f3|f4|f5|f6|f7        3
6                     g1|g2|g3|g4        6
```

Comment: I thank you very much. I wish you good health and happiness

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good health and happiness to you as well.